# What does "blowing on" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, slang

> Dean: I'm here to kick off the first day of a new tradition at our
>   school called Green Week
>
> Pierce: What? First we get a month of black
>   history, now we're **blowing** seven days **on** the Irish.
>
> — Community

It may be kind of a slangy phrase as it came from a TV show. I guess he was saying now he need to contribute seven days to the Irish— figuratively because of the colour green.

Is this the direct meaning of the phrase or a rhetorical one?

Can someone provide another example of this usage of *blow*?

Comment: Not necessarily *slang*, but definitely informal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"blow" in this context is a colloquial form meaning to **waste**, and can refer to time or money:

> I just **blew** all my money on a new car.
>
> We **blew** seven hours building a tree house and last night's storm
>   knocked it out of the tree!

In other contexts, it means to **ruin**:

> Don't tell her I got drunk last night - I don't want to **blow** my
>   chances with her.
>
> It's not every day you get an offer from a company like that - don't **blow** this opportunity!

The idiom **blow one's cover** means to reveal their true identity or hiding place:

> She really thinks I'm French. Don't **blow** my cover! (=don't reveal
>   the truth that I'm American)

Comment: You could also say "last night's storm _blew_ it out of the tree" — but that might only muddy the waters ;^)

Comment: That's exactly why I didn't use it :)

Comment: `Blow [a] cover` is more or less a specialized term, too. You wouldn't say `blow my makeup` or `blow my facade`.

Comment: ...which is why I didn't include those expressions

Answer (score 1):

This is being used as in [Merriam-Webster's definition 9a of the transitive verb form](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blow):

> to expend (as money) extravagantly

The adverb *extravagantly* is the key -- I wouldn't say *I blew 50 dollars on food this week*, since food is a necessity and 50 dollars is a reasonable amount (where I live, anyway). If, however, I threw caution to the wind and decided to get a whole new wardrobe, it would be appropriate to say *I blew 1000 bucks on clothes this weekend!*

In this case, the speaker thinks he's devoting quite enough time already to other cultures by having Black History Month, and an entire week for the Irish is just really pushing it.

It's quite a slang expression.

Comment: There's a famous joke that goes something like: _"I won $10,000 in the lottery. I spent $9,000 on beer and women — and then I just blew the rest."_ A synonym for _blew_ in this context might be _squandered_.

Comment: @J.R. That's a great synonym here.

Answer (score 0):

It's [sense 4 here...](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/blow)

> 1: **blow** [WITH OBJECT] INFORMAL Spend recklessly:
>   *they blew £100,000 in just eighteen months*

...which is effectively a "variant" of [sense 27 here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blue)...

> 2: **blue** (verb, tr) to spend extravagantly or wastefully; squander

Also note [this closely-related slang usage](http://www.englishdaily626.com/slang.php?018)...

> 3: **to blow it** to lose or waste something; to do very poorly or fail miserably.

---

It's worth pointing out that the example usage in #1 above could have appeared under #2 as

> 2a: *they **blued** £100,000 in just eighteen months*

My impression is that usage #2 is increasingly avoided precisely *because* it's being replaced by #1 and/or #3 - a replacement at least partly promoted by the fact that *to blue* is a "regular verb", so the present tense verb form sounds identical to the past tense of *to blow (blew)*.

Native speakers are slightly disconcerted by the overlap in the spoken forms for the different tenses. And because *both* verbs (blow/blue) are slang/informal in these usages, many people only know them in spoken rather than written contexts. Consequently, there are lots of native speakers who've never really noticed exactly how *to blue* is used. And perhaps become uncertain about exactly how they might *write* it. The net result of this confusion is people increasingly avoid #2 above, even though it's probably the *origin* of usage #1.

Comment: I've never heard of this use of *blue* before.  Is it BrE?

Comment: Perhaps I didn't explain myself very well. I would say it's almost 100% certain you *have* heard the usage many times - you just haven't noticed it because you assume you're hearing the past tense of *to blow*. The usage goes back to at least the mid 1800s, and is as much AmE as BrE. There's considerable uncertainty over the etymology - my own feeling is *to blue* here originally derived from "punning" on the past tense of *to blow* before the latter had its current sense. But in more recent times the *opposite* deerivation has kicked in for the exact modern sense as covered here.

Comment: If that's its origin, fine, I have no reason to argue with that, but it's clearly synchronically unrelated.  *Blow* and *blew* are in alternation in a clear inflectional paradigm and *blue* is unavailable in my idiolect.

Comment: @snailplane: You don't give "age" in your profile, but the implication of my answer is that *younger* speakers are increasingly likely to be unaware of the *blue = squander* usage even if older people around them are still using it (in *speech*). Obviously it's hard to avoid noticing if you come across it in *writing* - but because it's rather informal, you might never do that even if you read quite a lot (because it'll mainly be restricted to "reported speech" in particular types of fiction that you might *not* usually read).